# Sull'esistenza della "contrazione" nella lingua italiana

Tags: grammar

[Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrofo) ci dice che l'apostrofo, nella lingua italiana, può essere usato in tre casi:

1. Elisione
2. Troncamento
3. Aferesi

Se si consulta la pagina sull'[elisione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisione), si viene subito a sapere che quando, per esempio, si contrae un *ci*, come in *c'impedisce*, questa è sempre un'elisione. La mia domanda si collega a questa definizione. Wiki dice:

> ci dev’essere continuità con la grafia normale dei suoni

Da quel che si può capire qui, quindi, la contrazione di, per esempio, *al riguardo* in *a'riguardo* (pronunciato *arriguardo*) non è ortograficamente corretta, o sbaglio? C'è una continuazione morfologica, ovvero sia *l* che *r* sono due consonanti liquide, ma non c'è una continuazione ortografica, cosa che mi fa sorger il dubbio sopracitato.

Comment: Scusa, potresti chiarire meglio qual è esattamente la tua domanda? Stai chiedendo solo la grafia di “al riguardo”?

Comment: In pratica sí, ovvero, è corretta come contrazione?

Comment: Sicuramente in italiano moderno non è prevista una grafia come *“a'riguardo”. Poi, personalmente, non credo neppure che sia pronunciato sempre “arriguardo” o, per lo meno, non con l'unanimità con cui “c'era” è pronunciato /'tʃera/.

Comment: Intendevo “...è pronunciato /'tʃɛra/”...

Comment: Sicuramente "a'riguardo", pronunciato "arriguardo", è corretto per i romani (p.e. 'arriguardo delle nubbi'). Gli altri italiani userebbero 'a riguardo'.

Comment: @CarloAlterego, “al riguardo” e “a riguardo” sono due cose diverse: il primo significa “a tal proposito”, mentre il secondo (con “a” o con “al”) si usa nella locuzione “a(l) riguardo di” nel senso di “al confronto con, rispetto a”. (E, a parte questo, il romanesco non è il tuo forte, vero?)

Comment: In ogni caso, non so che cosa dica la Wikipedia, ma secondo l'[Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/contrazione_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), la contrazione è un fenomeno che riguarda solo le vocali, il che taglia la testa al toro.

Comment: Grazie a tutti per l'aiuto, é stata una discussione fruttuosa.

Answer (score 4):

**La grafia** ***a'riguardo*** **non è corretta**

I motivi sono due, entrambi già menzionati da @DaG:

- Come dice l'[Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/contrazione_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), la contrazione è un fenomeno che interessa solo le vocali (e quindi non si può applicare alla consonante *r*)

  > La contrazione è un fenomeno fonologico di fusione di vocali adiacenti, che nel caso estremo porta all’elisione di una delle due.
- Non tutti gli italiani pronunciano *a riguardo* o *al riguardo* come *a'riguardo*. Per esempio io non lo faccio, e non credo di averlo mai sentito (ma quei potrei sbagliarmi)